# Metrics well defined

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Please help me with item b.
I need to show the items (a) and (b):

a) Show that the function $d:l^\infty \times l^\infty \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$  given by $d (x, y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^i}|x_i-y_i|$ is well defined and is a metric in $l^\infty$.

b) Given $(\mu_{i})$ be a convergent real number sequence such that $\mu_i >0, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that the function $d:l^\infty \times l^\infty \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$  given by $d (x, y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu_i|x_i-y_i|$ is well defined and is a metric in $l^\infty$.

For item (a), I did as follows.

For all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $|x_i-y_i|\leq |x_i| + |y_i| \leq c_x + c_y = c$, so 
$$
d(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^i}|x_i-y_i| \leq 
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^i}c = c\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^i}. 
$$
As the series on the right side converges, then $d (x, y)$ converges to a real number and so $d$ is well defined.

Ok. Now, my problem consist in showing that the function $d$ is well defined in item (b).
In the same way as item (a), we know that $| x_i | <c_x$ and $| y_i | <c_y$.

So 
$$
\mu_i|x_i-y_i| \leq \mu_i(|x_i|+|y_i|) \leq c \mu_i,
$$
then we have 
$$
d(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu_i|x_i-y_i| \leq 
        c\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu_i. 
$$
Now I cannot prove that the series on the right side converges. I know the sequence $(\mu_i)$ converges, but I cannot show anything referring to the series formed by the sequence $(\mu_i)$.

Comment: As my example shows it is only natural you are struggling with part b), because it is not always true. Maybe in b) you should be restricted to sequences in $\ell^1$?

Comment: @K.Power I think that is a "trick" question how you said below. Thanks so much for your help me. I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b) is clearly not a well defined metric given your conditions. Consider $x=(0,0,0,\dots)$, $y=(1,1,1,\dots)$, and $(\mu_n)=(\frac{1}{n})$. Then
$$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}|1-0|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}.$$
We know that the  harmonic series diverges, so $d$ cannot be a well defined metric, but it satisfies all the requirements given.